# What formula would I use to make a column automatically populate in excel when new data is loaded into a worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a report in Excel with 3 separate worksheets, the main one where data is reported and calculated, one for new data and one for old data. I want values in one column in the main worksheet to update when new information is moved into the new data worksheet but still see values that were in the old data that may have dropped off the new list.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Connect to an Excel table or range

`Click the Data tab, then > From Table/Range.`

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/connect-to-an-excel-table-or-range-power-query-67538004-cd12-4b61-9cee-8720db1c7136